# Sum with Binomial Coefficients to Floor Function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

all!

I have recently begun my studies in an upper-level discrete mathematics course.  So far, I have quite enjoyed all of the lectures.

I recently came across an exercise on a supplemental homework requesting me to compute a trio of three binomial sums containing floor functions:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor} {n \choose 3k}$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor} {n \choose 3k+1}$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor} {n \choose 3k+2}$$

About an hour ago, I had not even heard of ceiling and floor functions.

I have tried to work the first sum out, but I really am not sure how to continue with these floor functions, nor am I sure how to truly approach these sums.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you all for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: The floors are not actually a problem here. What do you know about binomials ? do you know z-Transform ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $a_n$ be your first summation, and $b_n,c_n$ be the second and third. Start by computing these exactly for small values of $n$. You should start to notice a general pattern emerging. Describe the pattern exactly, then prove that it holds in general using induction on $n$. Use the base cases
$$
a_0 = 1, b_0=0,c_0=0
$$
and the rules
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+c_n,\qquad b_{n+1}=b_n+a_n,\qquad c_{n+1}=c_n+b_n
$$
The rule $a_{n+1}=a_n+c_n$ can be proven by applying Pascal's identity to each summand in $a_{n+1}$, and then splitting into two summations, which will be exactly $a_n$ and $c_n$.